# How to determine compiler is currently in ARC mode?

Tags: automatic-ref-counting, clang, compiler-flags

I have several `inline static` C functions. And I call Objective-C codes including `[-release]`.

The problem is I have to compile this code both of ARC or non-ARC targets. So I think I need conditional compilation by predefined compiler flag. What flag should I use for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2011/Aug/msg00252.html:

> The LLVM Compiler's checks are called `__has_feature`. ARC is one of the
>   features you can check for.
>
> ```
> #ifndef __has_feature
> // not LLVM Compiler
> #define __has_feature(x) 0
> #endif
>
> #if __has_feature(objc_arc)
> // compiling with ARC
> #else
> // compiling without ARC
> #endif
> ```